# no veo el fallo en el codigo bin/bash

Tags: linux, menu, ldap

```
#!/bin/bash

#BIENVENIDOS AL MENU , LAS FUNCIONES DE ESTE SON AQUELLAS QUE APARECERAN EN PANTALLA
 while :
  do
    #MENU DE FUNCIONES
        echo "1) Buscar un usuario en el LDAP:"
        echo "2) Introducir un usuario en el LDAP:"
        echo "3) Eliminar un usuario en el LDAP:"
        echo "4) salir"
        echo""
        #escogemos ahora una opcion del menu
        echo -n "escoge una opcion: "
        read opcion
        case $opcion in
            1) echo -n Introduce el usuario que deseas buscar:
                read usuario
                ldapsearch -xLL -b "dc=LaTerapia,dc=com" uid=$usuario sn givenName mail
            ;;
            2)  echo -n introduce el usuario que deseas agregar:
                read uid
                echo -n introduce la unidad organizativa: 
                read ou
                echo -n introduce los componentes del dominio:
                read dc
                echo -n introduce la extension del dominio:
                read dc
                ######################
                echo objectClass: top
                echo objectClass: posixAccount
                echo objectClass: inetOrgPerson
                echo objectClass: person
                ######################
                echo -n introduce nuevamente el nombre que deseas introducir para el usuario:
                read name
                echo cn: $name
                echo -n introduce nuevamente el nombre:
                read name2
                echo uid: $name2
                echo sistemas..recursos_humanos..psicologos_empresa..psicologos_autonomos
                echo -n introduce el grupo al cual deseas agregar al usuario:
                read grupo
                echo ou: $grupo
                echo uidNUmber: 3000
                echo gidNumber: 10000
                echo hombreDirectory: /home/emily/usuarios/$uid.ldif
                echo loginShell: /bin/bash
                #########################
                var=$(sudo slappasswd)
                echo userPassword: $var
                echo -n introduce tu apellido:
                read apellido
                echo sn: $apellido
                echo mail: $uid@LaTerapia.com
                echo givenName: $uid
                echo sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=LaTerapia,dc=com -W -f $uid.ldif
            ;;
            3) read -p "introduce el usuario que deseas eliminar:" $user
                read -p "introduce el grupo al cual  pertenece el usuario:" $grupo
                ldapdelete -x -W -D 'cn=admin,dc=LaTerapia,dc=com' "uid=$user,ou=$grupo,dc=LaTerapia,dc=com"
            ;;
            4) exit 0;;
                ##ALERTA
                    *)echo "opcion invalida..."
                        sleep 1
esac

 done
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: los echo debe tener comillas dobles o simples

Comment: Comenzó bien con los textos de los echo entre comillas. Ya después todo se derrumbó ;) Para próximas preguntas, es importante indicar qué errores encuentras (el mensaje completo) para que te ayuden más rápido.

Comment: los he corregido pero es que no me da error alguno

Comment: @Mimi los echo se puede sustituir por ``read -p "texto informativo: " variable`` y te ahorras todos esos echo ya que lo pone en un read y donde pones 4 salir abajo el ``echo""`` está mal debe tener un espacio ``echo " "`` también no hace falta poner ``$variable`` en el ``read -p " " variable`` sin el $

Comment: Creo que no te da error porque es un fallo de logica

Comment: hace falta una explicación de que se supone que haga el código y que esta obteniendo ...

Comment: @Mimi cual es el objetivo, que debe cumplir este programa :-)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya lo que tiene que hacer son las siguientes cosas: 1) buscar el usuario en el ldap 2)ingresar un usuario en el ldap 3)eliminar un usuario del ldap y 4) salir

Comment: Dale a [edit] para mejorar la pregunta con los detalles relevantes. Sobre el código en sí, intenta proporcionar un [mcve] en lugar de todo entero. Además, para errores gramaticales generales de Bash, https://www.shellcheck.net te da buenas pistas.

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón debes de editarlo :-)

Comment: @Mimi lo has solucionado?